ESD protection device selection
I want to select a ESD protection IC for my circuit with the following conditions:

Battery based and ultra-low-power
Battery voltage 3.6 V
My sensitive chips inside my circuit has Absolute Maximum Ratings of 4.1 V, so I should not allow the input voltage reach this voltage.

My first question is that what should be the value for the following parameters of the ESD chip for this circuit:

Breakdown Voltage:
Clamping Voltage:
Working voltage:

My second question is that what is the difference between Breakdown Voltage and Clamping Voltage in ESD chip?
My third question is what reverse polarity circuit should I use for my circuit to not lose a lot of voltage and power over it, considering the circuit is ultra low power and  the battery voltage is 3.6 V and my circuit also works at 3.3 V, so there is no that much room to loose a lot of voltage and power over the reveres polarity circuit, in fact the ideal case is that I do not lose any power over the reverse polarity circuit.


I would revisit your requirement for reverse polarity protection if your power budget is tight. There are other ways to protect your circuit that don't incur the power hit (e.g. polarized connectors). You don't mention a DC/DC converter; are you planning on running the circuit directly off of lithium ion cells? If so, how will they be charged? In-circuit or removed?

@vir yes using a polarized connector can also be an good idea. My battery is long life battery (non-chargeable battery). Regarding this parameters Breakdown Voltage, Clamping Voltage, Working voltage, would you please let me know how should I choose them? for my application?

What lines are you trying to protect? Power? Data? Everything? Do your sensitive chips interface directly with external sensors or connectors? Do they already have built in ESD protection capabilities?

@vir in fact I want to protect the VCC of the MCU, so it is just power protection. "Do your sensitive chips interface directly with external sensors or connectors?, No, they do not"

This is probably what you'd want to do, I realize that your source is different (3.6V):

How to protect input against both ESD and reverse polarity?
There is a TVS diode that turns on to block ESD, you would probably want to size it so it's a lower voltage, maybe like 10V but not low enough that some other spike could send lots of current through the TVS. This is a good article on TVS parameters
There is a pmosfet that does the reverse polarity protection, after that you could include another diode (4V) to block any additional voltage, you may want to consider a fuse also if you think that there is any potential for human error on plugging in something that is larger than 4V.

♦ thanks for the nice answer, would you please let me know in case i want to just consider ESD protection, how should I choose these values (Breakdown Voltage, Clamping Voltage, Working voltage)? to fit my application?

Need to know what your expected voltage voltage range is for the input, including voltages that would be accidental. You want the TVS diode to only be for ESD and not turn on if someone incorrectly plugs in a device to your device. What exactly is the input?

Also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

my input is a 3.6 V long life battery, so the maximum input voltage is 3.6V. The intention of the ESD diode is to reject the ESD when someone is plugging the battery connector to the board, regarding the reverse polarity i will probably use polarized connector. But regarding  ESD, i still need to know how should consider this  values (Breakdown Voltage, Clamping Voltage, Working voltage)?)

You would probably not want to exceed the Drain and source parameters of the FET (if you use one), so most of them are like 20V for Vds. If that's the case then you could select a TVS diode to turn on (breakdown voltage) at or below 20V something like 16V would be a good starting point. The clamping voltage is what the diode keeps the voltage to (upper bound)
